# AWS: What is the right way of PostgreSQL integration with Kinesis?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-kinesis

The aim that I want to achieve:
is to be notified about DB data updates, for this reason, I want to build the following chain: `PostgreSQL` -> `Kinesis` -> `Lambda`.

But I am now sure how to notify `Kisesis` properly about DB changes?

I saw a few examples where peoples try to use [`Postgresql` triggers](https://blog.dbi-services.com/sending-postgresql-data-to-aws-s3-by-using-aws-kinesis-data-streams/) to send data to `Kinesis`.

some people use [`wal2json`](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/stream-changes-from-amazon-rds-for-postgresql-using-amazon-kinesis-data-streams-and-aws-lambda/) concept.
So I have some doubts about which option to choose, that why I am looking for advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage Debezium to do the same.

Debezium connectors can also be intergrated within the code, using Debezium Engine and you can add transformation or filtering logic(if you need) before pushing the changes out to Kinesis.

Here's a [link](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.3/connectors/postgresql.html) that explains about Debezium Postgres Connector.

Comment: Are you confusing kinesis with kafka?

Comment: No, you can use Debezium connector to push changes to Kinesis. Not confusing Kinesis with Kafka.

Answer (score 0):

Debezium Server( Internally I believe it makes use of Debezium Engine).
It supports Kinesis, Google PubSub, Apache Pulsar as of now for CDC from Databases that Debezium Supports.

Here is an article that you can refer to for step by step configuration of Debezium Server
[https://xyzcoder.github.io/2021/02/19/cdc-using-debezium-server-mysql-kinesis.html][1]